# GCM failing to register with 1003 error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I am recompiling my iPhone app for iOS9 and am getting an error when trying to register for GCM, as below:

Registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 1003.)

I have look for a while now and cannot find anything on Google.
Can anyone help me on this one?

Thanks in advance

Code from appdelegate.swift below:

```
var connectedToGCM = false
var subscribedToTopic = false
var gcmSenderID: String?
var registrationToken: String?
var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()

let registrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"
let messageKey = "onMessageReceived"
let subscriptionTopic = "/topics/global"

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GCMConfig.defaultConfig())

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    //Process the deviceToken and send it to your server

    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for var i = 0; i < deviceToken.length; i++
    {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig())
    registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
        kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
}

func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!)
{
    if (registrationToken != nil)
    {
        self.registrationToken = registrationToken
        print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
        APIManager.sharedInstance.setDeviceToken(registrationToken)
        self.subscribeToTopic()
        let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
    else
    {
        print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we see some code? May help to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake on my side. 'GoogleService-Info.plist' was named incorrectly and placed in the wrong place and it was not in my build phase -> copy bundle resources.

Comment: I've placed it into the root folder of the project and added to my target. It was named GoogleService-Info.plist. However I am still receiving the same error; any idea?

Answer (score 3):

```
1003 error talks "Token request has invalid authorizedEntity."
```

In my case `gcmSenderID` was nil.

Maybe you didn't use `gcmSenderID` from `GoogleService-Info.plist`. To import settings from `GoogleService-Info.plist` insert this code

```
var configureError:NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
        gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
```

into

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Google error 1003

I had the GoogleService-info.plist in the root folder. 
In my case the gcmSenderID was not even null, but I was still getting this error.

But I was missing this code in AppDelegate.m file under didFinishLaunchingOptions.

> NSError* configureError;
>   [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
>   NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
>   _gcmSenderID = [[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configuration] gcmSenderID];